# How can I play the hold-music 1 time, then end conference?

Tags: twilio-twiml

I'm trying to find TwiML examples where user1 connects to the Conference w/ startOnEnter set to false, listens to hold recording, and if user2 has not connected by the end of the recording, the conference ends.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There's nothing built into Twilio that can handle that for you I'm afraid. So what I would recommend is that:

When your first user connects to the conference start a timer on your server for how long you want them to wait for. Also, with your `<Conference>` TwiML, register a [`statusCallback` URL](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/conference#attributes-statusCallback). When another participant joins the conference you will receive the webhook callback. At which point you can cancel the timer. If you receive no webhooks, then when the timer goes off you can [use the REST API to end the call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource?code-sample=code-update-a-call-resource-to-end-the-call&code-language=Node.js&code-sdk-version=3.x).

Comment: Thanks, Phil. That won't work for me because I'm using Twilio Runtime -- can't maintain a timer that long.

I've actually abandoned the conference approach and I'm doing it with the Video Rooms now.